# How to send mail by using mailto attribute of anchor tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I am using mailto attribute of anchor tag.But when I am clicking the link no new window gets openend.The code is :-

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="mailto:niru23@yahoo.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot send...you need a server to process your form and send the mail, `mailto:` will just open the default mail client in your computer

Comment: Please show the HTML, etc... you have so far.

Comment: Consider sending a POST request to the server requesting mail to be sent (and then using a server-side language to process the request) or use something like [this](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782).

Comment: @Mr.Alien please tell me how can I do so?

Comment: @YogitaNegi Learn PHP

Comment: To actually send an email you gotta need to know server side programming languages, like php. Once you know hot to create a server sided web applcation, php provides a mail() function http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Yogita Negi Hello Yogita try this link: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm

Answer (score 1):

Format you target attribute with value `_blank`  and then it will work.

```html
<html>
     <body>
           <a href="mailto:niru23@yahoo.com?Subject=subject message" target="_blank">Send Mail</a>
     </body>
</html>
```